# Cardinality of the untyped lambda calculus embedded in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

Haskell accepts the definition of the following type

```
data Lam = Func (Lam -> Lam)
```

which intends to represent [untyped lambda-terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus_definition). For example, Church's booleans are in this type

```
trueChurch :: Lam
trueChurch = Func (\x -> Func (\y -> x))
falseChurch :: Lam
falseChurch = Func (\x -> Func (\y -> y))
```

The constructor `Func :: (Lam -> Lam) -> Lam` has this inverse function

```
lamUnfold :: Lam -> (Lam -> Lam)
lamUnfold (Func f) = f
```

and those two functions define a type isomorphism between `Lam -> Lam` and `Lam`. This is surprising when we look at the cardinals (the sizes) of those types. Because of the Church booleans above, the cardinal of `Lam` is at least 2, so there are more elements in `Lam -> Lam` than in `Lam -> Bool`. The latter is the type of subtypes of `Lam`, i.e. the powerset of `Lam`, and by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) it already has much more elements than `Lam` does. How does the existence of type `Lam` not violate Cantor's theorem ?

Part of the answer might be in [domain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory). If I understand correctly, the elements of `Lam -> Lam` would not be all set-theoretic functions (which are bigger than `Lam` by Cantor's theorem), but only continuous functions. If so, what is the topology that defines this continuity, and why are Haskell terms of type `Lam -> Lam` continuous for it ?

Comment: If the cardinality of `Lam` were 1 (!), there would be no problem with having an isomorphism between `Lam` and `Lam -> Lam`. And now I ask you: can you write a Haskell program which effectively distinguishes between any two `Lam` values, say, your Church encoding of true and false? (This argument is easily fixed up by adding any way of making observations to `Lam`, like `data Lam = Lam (Lam -> Lam) | Bool Bool`, but I thought the observation might be amusing to you anyway.)

Comment: As an analogy, consider the set of real numbers R. It is not countable. Now, say you want to keep only those real numbers x for which there is an associated Turing machine that can tell you whether x is below, above, or equal to a given rational number p/q. These are called the *computable* real numbers. As the set of Turing machines is infinite but countable, there is only a countable infinity of computable real numbers. And requiring a Turing machine is very similar to requiring that a proper lambda term should be writable in Haskell using a finite sequence of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, the elements of `Lam -> Lam` would not be all set-theoretic functions (which are bigger than `Lam` by Cantor's theorem), but only continuous functions.

Yes, that's a common answer to the apparent paradox.

More in general, types are types, with their logical theory (type theory), while sets are sets (working as in set theory).

One is tempted to interpret types as sets, i.e. to constructs models of the lambda calculus within sets.

I suggest you read the milestone paper "Polymorphism is not set theoretic" by Reynolds. This shows that is you have "forall" types as in System F, and you interpret functions as sets in the "obvious" way, you get a contradiction, by a similar argument you made (Cantor's, roughly). Indeed, Reynolds constructs `T ~= (T -> Bool) -> Bool`.

Reynolds suggests indeed, one of the option is to interpret function types as a "subset" of functions on sets, e.g. continuous functions as you mentioned.

> If so, what is the topology that defines this continuity

Scott topology.

> and why are Haskell terms of type `Lam -> Lam` continuous for it ?

Roughly, because all the basic operations (lambda abstractions, applications, ...) are continuous, so you get a composition of continuous operators which has to be continuous.

Note that defining a proper formal semantics of Haskell is a daunting task. Even focusing on System F only, which is much simpler in comparison, models are already rather complex.

You could start from the simply-typed lambda calculus and learn about their categorical models: Cartesian closed categories (CCCs). Working in, say, the category of Scott-continuous functions is a special case of CCC. The CCC general structure makes you understand that, after you have a basic structure (essentially Currying and little else) you can use that to create a full-model, interpreting any (typed) lambda term.

Comment: “Roughly, because all the basic operations (lambda abstractions, applications, ...) are continuous, so you get a composition of continuous operators which has to be continuous.” – that is certainly true for all _finite_ compositions, but does this still hold if we consider fixpoint combinators? I don't think so.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm essentially talking about the syntax of a lambda term, which is surely finite. Or, if you prefer, by recursion on the typing rules. If you have `fix` in your terms, you need a semantic `FIX` operator. And yes, we do have a least-fixed-point operator `FIX` which is Scott-continuous from the topological space of Scott-continuous endofunctions on pointed-DCPO `A` to `A` itself, as expected.

Comment: Well, that would seem to be because you require the partial order to be complete by axiom. But why should this be applicable here? — In Haskell, we can in fact write “syntactically infinite” expressions by using `let`, which the lambda interpretation doesn't see as such.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not sure I understand your point. As far as I know, pointed DCPOs are a way to solve recursive definitions. There is a canonical way to interpret PCF (= STLC+fix) in pointed DCPOs, by induction on the finite syntax. If you want to use a different structure you are free to, but you'll need another way to solve fixed points.

Comment: Thanks, I just read the Reynolds paper. It is amusing how notations changed, his $e \in E_{\pi \omega}$ would nowadays be written $\pi \vdash e : \omega$. However the semantics he refutes do not need to be surjective. If we simply force the denotations of functions to be continuous set functions, it seems his refutation still applies. Or does his conclusion mean that the isomorphism `T ~= (T -> Bool) -> Bool` can be solved if we restrict the morphisms ?

Comment: @V.Semeria IIRC, Reynolds only proved that sets (and unrestricted functions sets) won't work. I believe in the conclusion he suggested continuity as a way out, but not necessarily the only way. To prove it's actually possible to solve such equations in domain theory there are other papers. Googling "recursive domain equations"  should find some. I think the Abramsky-Jung chapter on domain theory provides some results on that and/or some pointers.

Comment: Actually continuity really is a way out, because a continuous semantics does not automatically lift into an unrestricted set semantics. If we have denotations of functions f : X -> Y by continuous set-functions [f] : C^0([X], [Y]), a functional g : (X -> X) -> X is denoted by [g] : C^0(C^0([X],[X]), [X]). The domain of [g] is C^0([X],[X]), and [g] does not automatically extend to a function ([X] -> [X]) -> [X]. In other words, Reynolds does not refute continuous semantics.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the simplest way to resolve the paradox is to observe that not every (set-theoretic) function is representable as a lambda term.

Every valid lambda term can be obtained by choosing a finite number of grammar productions from an at most countable set and applying them at most finitely many times.  As such, the set of all lambda terms is a countable union of countable sets, and therefore it is itself countable.<sup>0</sup>  The argument transparently applies to the Haskell type: the only way to obtain terms of type `Lam` is to invoke the constructor, and at any given point in time, even if your program doesn’t terminate, the constructor may have been invoked only a finite number of times.  As such, during its whole execution, the program may encounter at most countably infinite number of different `Lam` values.  In practice, given that computer memory is finite, the number of terms your programs will actually be able to manipulate will be a little smaller.

Set-theoretically, nothing stops you from considering a bit string obtained by tossing a coin a countably infinite number of times to be a valid function ℕ → : it satisfies the set-theoretical definition of a function, since it assigns exactly one element of the codomain (the result of the coin toss) to each element of the domain (the position in the bit string).  But given that constructing such a function requires making an infinite number of arbitrary choices<sup>1</sup>, it has no corresponding lambda term.

(More formally: add a symbol *f* to the language of ZFC, and for each natural number *n*, randomly choose one of ‘*f*(*n*) = 0’ or ‘*f*(*n*) = 1’ as an axiom.  If we pick a finite subset of axioms defining *f*, it is obviously consistent with ZFC that a function satisfying that finite subset exists.  By the [compactness theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactness+theorem), it is consistent with ZFC that a function *f* satisfying all the axioms exists.)

There is no need to invoke complicated concepts like continuity.  All the above follows just from considerations of cardinality itself while paying attention to where lambda terms (and type terms in Haskell) come from.

---

<sup>0</sup> This is technically false if you start with an uncountable set of symbols for variables.  But even then, you can choose a countably infinite subset of lambda terms to which every lambda term in the full set will be α-equivalent.  The issue also disappears if you use de Bruĳn indices instead of variable symbols.

<sup>1</sup> Assuming the coin tosses are truly nondeterministic and independent, of course.

Comment: The coin-toss example is great. I would follow up with considering how you're going to distinguish such a set-function from a Haskell function based on `iterate sha256 865473876574263598`.

Comment: A set-theoretic function is a set. It must be defined from the axioms of set theory, like ZFC. So the infinite coin toss does not define a set. Can you provide a correctly defined set function `Lam -> Lam` that is not represented as a Haskell term ?

Comment: @V.Semeria: How about the function that takes (lambda-encoded) turing machines to (lambda-encoded) True if they halt, and (lambda-encoded) False, otherwise?

Comment: @psmears Yes indeed. And it may be the simplest answer : the Haskell type `Lam -> Lam` contains computable functions only, and there are a lot less of them than set-theoretic functions.

Comment: @V.Semeria The axioms of set theory don’t settle precisely which sets are and aren’t allowed to exist. They establish what properties sets have and that some sets must definitely exist, but other sets, not postulated by the axioms, may exist as well. Look up the continuum hypothesis, V = L, zero sharp, large cardinal axioms… all of these are essentially postulates that certain sets exist, which do not follow from ZFC.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not convinced there's much merit resolving this with notions of Scott continuity. Haskell doesn't have the kind of formal semantics that would be required for these mathematical arguments. There is [a bit of a philosophical war](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/) on whether this means *Haskell is broken* or rather *theorists keep overthinking stuff*, to put tongue-in-cheek. IDK.

Some issues showing that the Cantor argument just doesn't grip here:

- Arguably, `Lam` has in fact only **cardinality 1**, because there's no way you could actually distinguish two values. The only thing you can possibly do with `x :: Lam` is to apply the contained function to another `y :: Lam` to get... yet another `z :: Lam`. Sure, all these may have different code and runtime etc., but they're all equivalent in terms of you never get any Haskell values that would have observably different WHNF or something like that.
  This doesn't exactly settle the discussion because you could readily add another constructor and make a similar argument, but it won't be quite as simple.
- Haskell functions are not in fact functions, specifically they're not total. I could also write an “isomorphism”

  ```
  f :: Bool -> Maybe Bool
  f False = Just True
  f True = Just False

  f' :: Maybe Bool -> Bool
  f' (Just False) = True
  f' (Just True) = False
  f' Nothing = f' Nothing
  ```

  Good luck finding an `x` such that `f (f' x)` terminates with a value not equal to `x`. (Of course it just won't terminate *at all* for `x = Nothing`, but now good luck solving the halting problem...)

Comment: Re: "Haskell functions are not in fact functions, specifically they're not total": This is true, but doesn't it just exacerbate the problem? There are at *least* as many Haskell functions from type *A* to type *B* as there are true functions from type *A* to type *B*, because a Haskell function from type *A* to type *B* is in fact a function from type *A* to the union of type *B* with {⊥}.

Comment: (And if we include non-total functions, then this also weakens the "Lam has cardinality 1" argument IMHO, since a function that never terminates is distinct from one that does, even if *from inside Haskell* we can't distinguish them because we can't execute the former within a finite amount of time. But +1 anyway for the "Lam has cardinality 1" argument, because it's a good point so long as we restrict ourselves to pure functions.)

Comment: Haskell only supports computational equality (typeclass `eq`, valued in `Bool`). However we can still reason about propositional equality with pen and paper, or automated tools outside Haskell. When we accelerate a calculation `f : Nat -> Nat`, we produce another function `g : Nat -> Nat` equal in the sense forall n, f n = g n. On `Lam`, define propositional equality as usual with alpha conversion, beta reduction and the like. Also, always restrict Haskell functions where they are defined, so that your f' starts from Bool. The halting problem is trivially solved logically, by excluded middle.

Comment: @V.Semeria you can do all of this in special cases, but it's delusional to think you could come up with a proof of propositional equality for any two algorithms that are in fact equivalent. And to see that the halting problem is _not_ “trivially solved” doesn't require more than implementing Collatz sequences, which of course you can do in Haskell. To actually avoid nontermination, you need to do something like Coq with requiring recursion to decrease the function's input.

Comment: Using classical logic, you don't need to know when an algorithm halts (or when a Collatz sequence reaches 1). You simply call the excluded middle axiom, arguing that either the algorithm halts or it does not, and use that in a definition by cases, for example by sending diverging algorithms to ⊥, as @ruakh suggests. Of course this definition is not valid in constructive logic, but we can try solving the paradox classically first.